# Writing in pre written excel file

Tags: pyqgis

I am a bit new in python now working in qgis to automates some task. I have an excel pre-written template file where I have to add different data in different columns.

```
outpufFile = open('d:/template.xlsx','w')
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    print layer.name() +","+ str(layer.featureCount())
    line = layer.name()
    unicode_line = line.encode('utf-8')
    outpufFile.write(unicode_line)
outpufFile.close()
```

I get this so far but it corrupting my template while I also don't know how to access specific column or row of my file In order to write at exactly column and row to full my template.

Comment: Excel fomat is not a simple text format, you need to use a Python module for that :    [Python Package Index (Pypi): Excel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=excel&submit=search)

Comment: @gene how do i install plugin?

Comment: They are not plugins but simple Python modules/libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As say in my comment, I will use specific Python modules:

1) [openpyxl](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/index.html) (pure Python module, easy to install in the Windows, Linux and Mac OS X QGIS distributions)

A simple template

[image]

```py
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('template.xlsx')
# # grab the active worksheet but you can choose others
ws = wb.active
for index, layer in enumerate(QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()):
    ws.cell(row=index+2, column=1).value = layer.name()
    ws.cell(row=index+2, column=2).value = layer.featureCount()

# as template.xlsx is a template, we create another file
wb.save('result.xlsx')
```

Result

[image]

2) you can also the more general [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) (present in the Windows distribution of QGIS, easy to install in the Linux and Mac OS X distributions)

```
import pandas as pd
# convert Excel file to Pandas Dataframe
templ= pd.read_excel('template.xlst', sheetname='Sheet1')
print templ.head()
 Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [name, count]
 Index: []
# populate the DataFrame
counts = [layer.featureCount() for layer in   QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()]
names = [layer.name() for layer in  QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()]
templ['name'] = names
templ['count'] = counts
print  templ.head()
        name     count
0       compa1    100
1       compa2    300
2       compa3    500
3       compa4     10
# convert Pandas Dataframe to Excel 
templ.to_excel('result2.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Result

[image]

Comment: openpyxl installation is a problem http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212461/writing-in-pre-written-excel-file

Comment: Then use Pandas    (openpyxl installation is not a problem if you know Python)

Comment: Remember: for openpyxl, et_xmlfile and jdcal packages required first –

Answer (score 0):

Althoug @Gene answer is enough but for future users I want to share some details about the answer(as I face much difficulty).

I used [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) Package for excel template writing but before using this package you have require:  [**et_xmlfile**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/et_xmlfile) and [**jdcal**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jdcal/1.3) packages also (it is requirement).

Then I extract all three(openpyxl,jdcal,et_xmlfile ) in my D drive(You can do it in any drive). [You have required to append it first in python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212634/how-to-install-python-plugin-in-qgis).
Then i used this code

```
    #For Writing in Excel File
    import sys
    #For openpyxl-2.4.0 Python Package you should need to have et_xmlfile and jdcal package

    sys.path.append("D:\et_xmlfile-1.0.1")
    sys.path.append("D:\jdcal-1.3")
    sys.path.append('D:\openpyxl-2.4.0')

    import openpyxl
    from openpyxl import Workbook

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\template.xlsx') #loading template

    # grab the active worksheet
    ws = wb.active
    ws['C1'] = "This will save in C1"
    #save in d drive with result name
    wb.save('D:\Result.xlsx')
```

Comment: Just use `pip install openpyxl`

Comment: this didn't work for me. i tried it