# How to install python plugin in qgis

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have downloaded [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl/2.4.0) plugin rar file now i want to use it in QGIS. How can i do this? while i also search this plugin in qgis plugin search it didn't find.  Do all python plugin are not avaialbe in qgis plugin  search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a qgis plugin rather a python package.  You will have to un-zip the .rar file to expose the folder/python binding files.  You will either have to register the package or use the sys module to append it to your python library so you can use its methods within either the python console or build your own plugin and call its methods.

```
# sys append example
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Temp/path/to/pythonPackageFolder')
import pythonPackageFolder
```

Comment: what are you talking ? i am completely not know. where to put my rar folder ? how do i access it?

Comment: Do i need to copy my package into E:\QGIS Setup\apps\Python27\Lib ? then use your above code?

Comment: The package can be extracted to any directory that QGIS can access.  It is not tied to QGIS or any other app like @gene answer.  For questions how to access it, it is really out of scope of this forum to answer those unless you have a posted code example of calling it within a GIS app and letting us know where you are stuck.

Comment: Ok when i try this
 code import sys
sys.path.append('D:\openpyxl-2.4.0')
import openpyxl

Comment: it give me error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:/users/faizan~1/appdata/local/temp/tmpsukdk2.py", line 3, in <module>
    import openpyxl....................................

Comment: Remember: for openpyxl, et_xmlfile and jdcal packages required first

Answer (score 0):

There is a confusion among QGIS, ArcGIS (or GRASS GIS, or..) users.

These programs use Python for scripting but they are not Python.

- For example, QGIS uses Python in the console with the Python module `qgis` and plugins written in Python.
- But [Python](https://www.python.org/) is a widely used high-level, general-purpose, interpreted, dynamic programming language (nothing to do with QGIS, ArcGIS, GRASS GIS, ...)

If you want to install a Python package/library/module ([openpyxl](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/index.html) for example), you install it with Python and not with QGIS and I think it is not the purpose of GIS Stack Exchange to explain it.

There are countless courses, tutorials on the Web, many many books and ...

- [Installing Python Modules (Legacy version): setup.py](https://docs.python.org/2/install/)
- [Installing Python Modules: pip](https://docs.python.org/2/installing/index.html#installing-index)