# QGIS crashing when exporting data into Excel Spreadsheet with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, excel

I am extracting raster data using GDAL from a map that has different shades of red depending on the temperature. When I run the code within QGIS only the beginning and end of the code shows up. This is why I want to export the data into Excel, but QGIS keeps crashing when I run that part of the code. I have tried exporting the data into .csv and .txt formats but I get a Permission Denied error.

```
from osgeo import gdal

import pandas as pd

import openpyxl

layers=QgsProject.instance ().mapLayersByName ('1970-2000, 2.5, feb')

layer=layers [0]

ds=gdal.Open (layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri ())

dem_arr=ds.GetRasterBand (1).ReadAsArray ()

print (dem_arr)

df=pd.DataFrame (dem_arr)

df.to_excel ("colorfirst.xlsx")
```

Comment: Why not export it using pyqgis? I recommend this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/309117/120426

Comment: Thank you for the response. For QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, path, "utf-8", layer.crs(), 'xlsx') would I substitute the layer name as a string in place for the layer parameter. I tried this and it does not seem to work. Sorry, I am new to QGIS.

Comment: In fact, I get the error: overload 3: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsRasterLayer'

Comment: Sorry, the QgsVectorFileWriter class is used for vectoreal files. Would you like to export your data to xyz format (https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/xyz.html) and then to excel?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export your raster file to [xyz file](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/xyz.html), which you can open from Excel.
The conversion is done using GDAL alg.

```
import processing

layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('1970-2000, 2.5, feb')
layer = layers[0]
output = '/home/grand/Desktop/QGISOutputs/colorfirst.xyz'
    
# Export raster layer to xyz file
result = processing.run("gdal:translate", 
        {'INPUT': layer,
        'TARGET_CRS':None,
        'NODATA':None,  # Assign a specified nodata value to output bands.
        'COPY_SUBDATASETS':False,
        'OPTIONS':'',
        'EXTRA':'',
        'DATA_TYPE':0,
        'OUTPUT': output})
    
print('Your file was created: {}'.format(result['OUTPUT']))
```

Note: Verify that the output directory exists before running the script otherwise the output file will not be created

You can also use gdal directly to do the conversion:

```
gdal_translate -of XYZ /home/ai/Desktop/input.tif /home/ai/Desktop/output.xyz
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response but unfortunately I am getting no output file. There are no errors.

Comment: If you can share your file with me I can check what might be going on.

Comment: I posted what I did above. Thanks.